# UML class-diagram double association between classes

Tags: associations, uml, class-diagram

Does double association exist in UML? Let's say, for example that i have two classes: User and Account with their own attributes which are not important and that in the User class there should be exactly two attributes of type Account. 
In this type of scenario when making the UML class-diagram should there be a double association or is there another way to emphasise the fact that there are two attributes of that type?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact to model "a double association", I would use two associations which are useful to speficy a different role for each association as depicted below [image].

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had in mind, but I wasn't sure if it was correct

Comment: Only why "instead"? It is the double association she wanted.